# Missing Expression when using In statement

Tags: sql, oracle

While implementing the below query:

```
select distinct(city) 
from station 
where substr(distinct(city),1,1) IN ['A','E','I','O','U'];
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR at line 1: 
>   ORA-00936: missing expression

Using Oracle Sql.
I am still a beginner to using SQL so just can't figure this one out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two typos in your statement.

- use classical paranthesis instead of brackets.
- `distinct clause` cannot be used as an expression inside `substr
  function` (at the end results will already become `distinct`).

Make your sql like this :

```
select distinct(city) 
from station 
where substr(city,1,1) IN ('A','E','I','O','U');
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of writing distinct in where because you are going to get distinct value as you mention where selecting the column.
And Syntax for IN

```
expression IN (value1, value2, ... value_n);
```

Corrected Query

```
select distinct city
from station 
where substr(city,1,1) IN ('A','E','I','O','U');
```

Comment: `distinct` is not a function in SQL AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT city
FROM station 
WHERE SUBSTR(city,1,1) IN ('A','E','I','O','U')
GROUP BY city;
```

It's better to use `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT`.